# Browser compatibility issue in Only IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Could anyone please tell me why IE 9 browser taking '50' for 'Enter' keycode .It could have been taken 13 instead?

Please see the below javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stopRKey(evt) {
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {
            document.getElementById('body:frmTestTube:regNumberId').focu‌​s();
            if(node.name=='body:frmTestTube:regNumberId'){
                document.getElementById('body:frmTestTube:btnReg').focus();
            }
            return false;
         }
     }
     document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
</script>
```

I have10 fields in my page. After scanning a barcode to the first input field in IE 9 browser, remaining values should populates form DB (Oracle), but in IE 9 browser page is hanging. Its executing the above 'stopRKey' Javascript function and it should trigger the enter event and focus to the next field. Keycode for 'Enter' is 13, but in case of IE 9 it is taking as 50. This makes me trouble. I reckon I have to do some changes in the above Javascript function to generate or trigger 'Enter' event. Please help me. Hope it's clear now. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Could anyone please suggest me.

Comment: This is happening while scanning the barcode.

Comment: This is not a complete question. Please may you add the relevant (minimal) code in your question? I also, could you add more explanation to you question? It's hard to understand what you're asking...

Comment: Please, read this and re-write your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should use the [edit] button to add details to your question, not the comment button.